# Dificuldade em array

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um código porém da erro no array. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

Código principal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tanque {

    int valor;
    private int kmTotal = 0;
    private int gasolinaTotal = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int kmLitro(final int Quilometros, final int Litros) {
        return Quilometros / Litros;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getKmTotal() {
        return kmTotal;
    }

    public void setKmTotal(int kmTotal) {
        this.kmTotal = kmTotal;
    }

    public int getGasolinaTotal() {
        return gasolinaTotal;
    }

    public void setGasolinaTotal(int gasolinaTotal) {
        this.gasolinaTotal = gasolinaTotal;
    }

    public int tanques[][] = new int [2][valor]; {
        for (int i=0;i<=valor-1;i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite os quilometros dirigidos do "+(i+1)+"° tanque.");
        tanques[0][i] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        kmTotal =+ tanques[0][i];

        System.out.println("Digite os litros de gasolina gastos do "+(i+1)+"° tanque.");
        tanques[1][i] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        gasolinaTotal =+ tanques[1][i];
        }
    }
}
```

E o teste é :

```
public class TanqueTeste {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Tanque T = new Tanque();

        System.out.println("Quantos tanques foram testados?");
        T.setValor(sc.nextInt());       
        for (int j=0;j<=T.getValor()-1;j++) {
            System.out.println("A kilometragem por litro do "+(j+1)+"° Tanque é de "
                        + T.kmLitro(T.tanques[0][j],T.tanques[1][j]));
        }
        System.out.printf("A Quilometragem total é de: %d \n", T.getKmTotal());
        System.out.printf("A Quantidade de gasolina total é de %d \n",T.getGasolinaTotal());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Sei que tenho que invocar o metodo/array tanque mas não sei/entendi como ainda...

Comment: "porém da erro no array" - Qual o erro ? Qual o array ? Em que linha de código ? Invocar que método ?

Answer (score 0):

A classe Tanque deve representar os atributos e comportamentos de um e apenas um tanque.

Nessa parte do código: `public int tanques[][] = new int [2][valor]; {...}` existem dois problemas:
1. A sintaxe não está correta. Não entendi se estava tentando fazer uma variável ou um método, recomendo que revise esses conceitos e suas respectivas declarações.
2. Ela não pertence à essa classe. Como a classe Tanque é a representação de um tanque, seu array de tanques deve estar em outro lugar, no seu caso, no main.

Eg.

```
int kmTotal = 0;
int gasolinaTotal = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Quantos tanques foram testados?");
int quantidadeTanques = sc.nextInt();

Tanque[] tanques = new Tanque[quantidadeTanques];

for (int i = 0; i <= quantidadeTanques-1; i++) {
    tanques[i] = new Tanque();

    System.out.println("Digite os quilometros dirigidos do "+(i+1)+"° tanque.");
    tanques[i].setKmTotal(sc.nextInt());
    sc.nextLine();
    kmTotal =+ tanques[i].getKmTotal();

    System.out.println("Digite os litros de gasolina gastos do "+(i+1)+"° tanque.");
    tanques[i].setGasolinaTotal(sc.nextInt());
    sc.nextLine();
    gasolinaTotal += tanques[i].getGasolinaTotal();
}
```